# How to change highlight text color in terminator

Tags: terminal

I'm using terminator as default terminal on ubuntu. It's quite good but when i navigate on terminal. Folder is highlight by a color that isn't good to read. I try to change the color but i don't find any setting change hight light color.
Does anyone know these setting or is there any way to fix this problem.
[myterminator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxdoF.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Open terminator**

- right click in the terminal window -- you will see menu
- Choose Preferences
- Choose Profiles
- choose Colors
- Select your color theme you wish
- Or edit the colors manually as you wish

hope it helps you